# Mysql: One enum for multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have two tables:

```
mice
id (int) petname (varchar) gender (enum (male, female))
1        spot            male
2        rice           female

men
id (int) name (varchar) gender (enum (male, female))
1        bob            male
2        jane           female
3        steve          male
```

The gender enum exists twice. Once for each table. So if I wanted to expand the gender enum with new values, this would mean that I would have to manually edit the enums in several tables. This is suboptimal.

Is there any way to define the enum values once and use them in several tables?

Or perhaps to create a new table named genders and put the genders there, and then during inserts and updates into mice and men, it would only allow the gender column to contain values form the gender table. This check however needs to happen automatically (like with enum column type), so I don't have to execute additional queries first to check if the used gender exists in the gender table, before each update or insert query I want to run, which inserts a value into a gender column in mice or men.

Can this be done with mysql?

Comment: Foreign keys https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html ?

Answer (score -1):

You can forget about SQL's `enum`. Instead, just use `VARCHAR(50)`, etc, and use `const` in your PHP code to define the `enum` values.

I seldom use SQL's `enum`, in most cases, its benefit is less than its complexity。